# Half of the screen does not seem to work correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen

I am not such a professional coder but trying to code something on Unity. However, when I try to play the application in my android phone, the half of the screen does not seem to work correctly, please look at the photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXWAG.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv5Qz.png

Can you guess what the reason is for that?

Up to now, I have changed screen resolution but it did not solve my problem.

Edit: It works perfectly in my android tablet. However, as I said, I have this problem in my LG G3 android phone.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look at what position your layering is. The title and background layers may be at different heights cutting off half of your picture?

Comment: Hello Tom. Thank you for your response, I do not think that is the reason because in every screen of my application, I have same problem.

Comment: By the way, I also install the application to my android tablet, it works perfectly. However, as I said, I have this problem in my LG G3 android phone.

Comment: Could be to do with the phone itself if it works on another android device? Is the phone old/had a few knocks at the screen? However I'm unsure why only the app would have half the screen missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing Main Camera setting according to this photo: [image], I have solved my problem.